# RCX 2.0 usb ir tower. Easiest path to start

Tags: software, rcx

I picked up a working set recently and I would like to know the easiest path to get going. I have several old and new PCs and win 98, xp, 7 (32bit) and 10 available. The kit has no CD.

I have LabView on the win7 machine.

Comment: Oops. Got a bit ahead of myself. The win 98 machine isn't there anymore. Must have thrown it out last purge.

Comment: [This article is from 2017](https://www.bartneck.de/2017/06/08/using-your-lego-mindstorms-rcx-on-a-modern-computer/) and might be what you need, including a link I haven't tested for the software. But if you can get the XP machine working, the software was supposed to work directly - if you could find the patches from Lego.

[BrickLink has CDs for sale](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=4142876) including one for 64c.